# Why the file created in dockerfile RUN not on host, I already mount host dir for service

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to run my golang app.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.13
WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -o main .
CMD ["/app/main"]
```

and my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    app:
        build: ./myapp
        container_name: myapp
        volumes:
            - ./myapp:/app
```

When I run `docker-compose build` The `main` file not appear on `myapp` dir.

`docker-compose up myapp` not work, because `main` file not found.
But `docker run mypp` can work. How can i build main.go in dockerfile and stay the `main` in my host?

Comment: Your volume declaration mounts ./myapp to /app. Whatever you had in /app directory is hidden under this mount. Is there a reason why you're mounting that directory?

Comment: I want using docker to building go program, and modify source easily.

Comment: @Duoduo The `build:` line in the yml only gives `docker-compose build` its context for running `docker build .` (this builds your docker _image_, not your code). If you want to build your code in a container I would suggest using a watcher. You don't even need a Dockerfile or `build:` context, just mount in your source code from `./myapp`. See https://github.com/canthefason/go-watcher.

Answer (score 0):

A `docker-compose build` step runs to completion, ignoring everything else in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  The resulting image is then executed taking these options into account.  So the sequence you show does two things:

1. Build the image, `COPY`ing its source code in, and producing a `/app/main` binary inside the image; nothing on the host system is affected.
2. Run a container based on that image, but mounting the current `./myapp` directory and its contents over `/app` in the container, hiding anything there.

In this sequence of steps nothing ever gets copied out of the container, you are only ever pushing things into Docker space.  If you'd like to run the binary you built, delete the `volumes:` mount to let the image in the binary run.

In comments you suggest your goal is to just build the Go program and get a binary out.  You don't want Docker for that; the Go [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) page has instructions for how to install a Go toolchain, and you can just `go install` your program.